# No property 'birthDate' found for type 'person'! Did you mean ''birthdate''? in srping boot

Tags: sql, spring-boot, rest

I am developing and rest api and i want to filter a data by birthday. I create birthday variable as birthday in every where and when i compile my code  i get an error that " No property 'birthDate' found for type 'person'! Did you mean ''birthdate''?". But i haven't make a variable as birthDate

entity

```
public class person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private long id;


    @Column(name="Name")
    private  String name ;

    @Column(name="surname")
    private  String surname;


    @Column(name="Birthdate")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date birthdate;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = address.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name ="per_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<address> address = new ArrayList<>();
    
}
```

repository

```
public interface personRepository extends JpaRepository<person,Long> {

   public List<person> findByName(String Name);
   public List<person> findByBirthDate(Date birthdate);
}
```

controller

@GetMapping()
public List filterall(@RequestParam(required = false) String name, @RequestParam(required = false) Date birthdate){

```
//return  null;
var personsByName = repository.findByName(name);
var personsByBday= repository.findByBirthDate(birthdate);
return personsByBday;
```

}

error!

[image]

Comment: try changing `findByBirthDate(...)`  in `var personsByBday= repository.findByBirthDate(birthdate);
return personsByBday;` to `findByBirthdate(...)`

Comment: it doesnot  work for me